# Can't Set and Get cookie using C# under ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I'm trying to set and read cookies in c#. I wrote these two methods:

```
public static void setCookie(string sCookie, string value)
{
    HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[sCookie];
    if (cookie == null)
        cookie = new HttpCookie(sCookie);
    cookie.Value = value;
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
    HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Add(cookie);
}

public static string getCookie(string sCookie)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[sCookie] == null)
        return null;
    return HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[sCookie].Value;
}
```

But I don't know why when I read the method getCookie, after calling setCookie, the collection HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies contains always 2 elements, "__RequestVerificationToken" and "ASP.NET_SessionId", it doesn't contain my cookies...

Methods are not in any controller, just in a utils class, but I don't see any problem for that...

Can you figure out why my set method doesn't work?
Thank you!

Comment: can u show how u set and get cookie.may be u are trying set and get a cookie in the same request

Comment: exactly you have to use response.cookies.add

Comment: I'm using cookies to set the current culture, i.e. "en" "it" "es" and so on. I could get the added cookie in the same request, but however I expect that in the next request cookie is surely present...
I do use Response.Cookies.Add, as showed in my code, through HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Add(cookie);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set cookies to the Response object, also set the Path of a cookie

Comment: I use HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Add(cookie) if it is what you mean and the path is always "/" by default, and that's ok for me, I think

Comment: @RedPelle, please read the difference between `Request` and `Response`. It will make your life as a web developer much easier.

Comment: Changed the line
HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Add(cookie); 
with the line:
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
Sometimes you can read the same thing for an hour without reading it right... I don't know why I was stuck with writing in the Request, that doesn't make any sense  :)